# How to make a rule that contains several occurences of the same token?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm working with ANTLR4 to parse a simple script language.

This language uses the following syntax for `FOR` loops:

```
FOR [I] = 1 to [N]
   instructions
NEXT [I]
```

In order to be correct, a `FOR` loop must have exactly the same token after the `FOR` keyword and after the `NEXT` keyword.

For example, this is correct:

```
FOR I = 1 TO 10
NEXT I
```

While this is incorrect:

```
FOR I = 1 TO 10
NEXT J
```

So far I have a rule that look like this:

```
forloop
    : FOR VARNAME EQUAL INT TO INT instructions NEXT VARNAME
    ;
```

With the following related lexer rules (I removed constant keywords such as `FOR : 'FOR';`):

```
fragment ALPHA : [a-zA-Z_];
fragment ALPHANUM : [a-zA-Z_0-9];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
VARNAME : ALPHA ALPHANUM*;
INT : DIGIT+;
```

However, this rule will interpret as correct the second example that is actually incorrect.

How can I tell ANTLR4 that the second `VARNAME` must be the same that the first one in the rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* add a predicate at the end of your `forloop` rule that enforces that both `VARNAME`s are equal:

```
forloop
    : FOR a=VARNAME EQUAL INT TO INT instructions NEXT b=VARNAME
      {$a.getText().equals($b.getText())}?
    ;
```

But a (IMO) better way would be to let the parser just accept the unequal `VARNAME`s and check them after the parse has been completed (in some sort of validation listener that traverses the parse tree).

Comment: Thanks! Thinking about it, I think you're right, but it's good to know how to add such predicates anyway :)

Comment: Actually I'm using C# so I converted the predicate to C# code: `{$a.Text == $b.Text}?`. Sadly I have the following error: `error AC0066: attribute 'Text' isn't a valid property in '$a.Text'.` However if I break with the debugger (using a simple predicate that compiles), the Text property seems accessible and correctly defined (from the `IToken` interface). Anyone experienced such issue with C#?

Comment: @Benlitz, isn't there a `$a.GetText()` method then?

Comment: Actually I had to use lower-case `$a.text`, even though the C# property is Text. From the author of `antlr4cs`, this would work with java, too (see https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues/47).